# K&R c book exercise 5-3 strcat example

Tags: c, pointers

For this exercise, I modified a little bit and it stopped working!
I know where it stopped working, but I have no idea why it stopped...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 20
void concat(char *, char *);
int main(){
    char s[MAXLINE] = "hello,";
    char t[MAXLINE] = "world";
    concat(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
void concat(char *s, char *t){
    int index = 0;
    while(*s){
       s++;
    }
    while(*s++ = *t++)
            ;
}
```

I compile it with cc, and run it, it outputs **hello,world**, it looks great;
but I want to make the part more concise while(*s){s++;}
to be while(*s++) , it is even more simpler! but it stops working, the output is **hello,** , it's really hard to output something of the change value of s, so anyone can explain the logic behind? any help would be awesome!

Comment: `*s++` is different than `*s` `s++`. In your version the interment happens even when the condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3):

The first loop is there to position `s` so that it points to the terminating `0`. The problem with `++` is that it will increment *once more after* the condition already evaluated to false.

If you want to save keypresses, you can remove `{` and `}`.

Comment: ok, thx and I will try to print all the characters after concat to see if world is after null terminator...

Comment: U are right, it is **once more after** ! really tricky and good point! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Others have already explained that your proposed solution advances past the terminating '\0' of s.  You could do:

```
while(*s && s++);
```

but I think a for-loop expresses it more directly:

```
for(; *s; s++);
```

Comment: yeah, this is a good solution! and use && in the while loop in the test condition to achieve my goal! thx